# Error in curl - SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: r, ssl, curl, httr

I am having difficulty with a GET call that pings the US Naval Observatory API. This request was previously working, but now is failing for unknown reasons.

Here's the request:

```
library(httr)

#ping API
try(RETRY("GET", url = "http://api.usno.navy.mil/rstt/oneday?date=07/10/2018&coords=41.2792778,%20-96.06442261&tz=-5", times = 20))

#ERROR MESSAGE (request always times out with error)
#Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle): SSL certificate problem: #unable to get local issuer certificate
#Request failed [ERROR]. Retrying in 1 seconds...
```

I am running R v3.5.1 and RStudio v1.1.463. Curl is v3.2 and httr is v1.3.1.

What I have tried for troubleshooting that did not work:

- Double-checking US Naval Observatory API documentation to make sure the request is still correct/up-to-date (it is).
- Installing a previous version of R (v.3.4.4) that this call worked on (no change).
- Updating to latest version of RStudio (v.1.1.463, no change)
- Solution listed at this site ([quantmod - SSL: unable to get local issuer certificate in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46331066/quantmod-ssl-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-in-r)) which made no change. This is the only relevant thread for this error in R I could find online.

Any ideas fellow R users? Any help or points in the right direction is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It looks like the website might now require https and is signed with a certificate signer that doesn't seem to be commonly trusted. So it's probably a change on the server end, and not anything you can control. (I get a security warning in Chrome if i try to visit the URL). You might have to mess around with SSL certificates by hand to get it to work.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Was hoping you could help me understand - where would I play with the SSL certificates? Is this within R or elsewhere? Thank you for the help!

Comment: Try looking at these questions for advice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33913916/get-site-content-over-ssl-with-httr-in-r and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411313/ssl-verification-causes-rcurl-and-httr-to-break-on-a-website-that-should-be-le and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22048703/rcurl-and-self-signed-certificate-issues

Answer (score 0):

After some searching, found the answer. The API switched from http -> https, which caused the SSL error. Fixed by setting this parameter to httr before running "GET":

```
httr::set_config(config(ssl_verifypeer = 0L))
```

So if you modify the above API call like this, it works:

```
library(httr)
httr::set_config(config(ssl_verifypeer = 0L))

#ping API
try(RETRY("GET", url = "https://api.usno.navy.mil/rstt/oneday?date=07/10/2018&coords=41.2792778,%20-96.06442261&tz=-5", times = 20))
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: it looks like you're just disabling the certificate checking, is that right? If so, that's hardly a satisfying resolution to the problem...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with this website.  The error I was receiving was "`java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException`: Trust anchor for certification path not found.".

Several of the US Department of Defense (DOD) related websites are transitioning from `http` to `https`.  This website made the transition at the end of November of 2018.  The problem relates to the fact that the DOD SSL certificates are not signed by a normal trusted authority (checking against Mozilla's root store).  Just adding the traditional publicly available DOD Certificates did not fix the problem.

On January 31, 2019, I was notified by their help desk that they have now installed commercially recognized certificates.  After retesting my code (after removing some security bypasses), I no longer have any SSL errors and all appears to be working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get install ca-certificates` was all I needed to do on Ubuntu to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what @griffmer posted, though for me I had to use `httr::config` instead of just config. So that gives:

`httr::set_config(httr::config(ssl_verifypeer = FALSE))`